# Xamarin Android handle implicit intent for actionsend mimetype image

Tags: android-intent, xamarin, xamarin.android

In this application what i want is whenever a user select and share image from any fotos application, I want my application to be listed in the list of sharing applications.
this is what I got to handle this implicit action intent.

```
[IntentFilter(new string[] { Intent.ActionView },
Categories = new  string[] { Intent.ActionDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable,
Intent.ActionSend, Intent.ActionSendMultiple },
DataScheme = "mimetype",
DataPathPattern = "*/*",
DataHost = "*.*")]
```

To handle this image or images this is what i found,

```
Intent intent = Intent;

String action = intent.Action;

String type = intent.Type;

if (Intent.ActionSend.Equals(action) && type != null)
{

     if (type.StartsWith("image/"))
     {
           tv.Text = "single image sharable";
           //handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent

     }

}
else if (Intent.ActionSendMultiple.Equals(action) && type != null)
{

    if (type.StartsWith("image/"))
    {
       tv.Text = "multiple images sharable";
       //handleSendMultipleImages(intent); // Handle multiple images being sent
     }
}
```

Here now I try to share image from gallery but I don't see my application in the list.
So something must be wrong in intent filter.

Comment: The intent filter listed contains an incorrect category. Instead of "Categories = new string[] { Intent.ActionDefault }", it should be Intent.CategoryDefault instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IntentFilter` examples for sharing single or multiple images:

```
[IntentFilter(
    new string[] { Intent.ActionSend }, 
    Categories = new string[] { Intent.CategoryDefault },
    DataMimeType =  "image/*"
)]
[IntentFilter(
    new string[] { Intent.ActionSendMultiple },
    Categories = new string[] { Intent.CategoryDefault },
    DataMimeType = "image/*"
)]
[Activity(Label = "Share data to this activity", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (Intent.Action == Intent.ActionSend)
        {
            Log.Debug("Share", Intent.Type);
        }
        else if (Intent.Action == Intent.ActionSendMultiple)
        {
            Log.Debug("Share", Intent.Type);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: When using Class-based `AndroidManifest` `Attributes`, I highly recommend reviewing the generated `AndroidManifest.xml` in the `Debug|Release` directory to ensure that you are generating the correct entries.

```
YourAndroidProjectDirectory/Debug/android/manifest/AndroidManifest.xml
```